# "How to fix' ImportError: cannot import name 'SQLAlchemy'

Tags: python-3.x

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
import sqlalchemy
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

bsdir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
# print(bsdir)

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder = 'template')


app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///'+os.path.join(bsdir,'data.sqlite')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATION'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
class Puppy(db.Model):
    pass
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "D:\PYTHON\GIT_EXC\FLASK_\flask_sqlalchemyex.py", line 5, in
>   
>       from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy   File "D:\PYTHON\GIT_EXC\FLASK_\flask_sqlalchemy.py", line 4, in 
>       from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy ImportError: cannot import name 'SQLAlch

Comment: gyes i have install and uninstall so many times. But i cont resolve this. any one help me for that problem. im using windows 7 32 bit.

Comment: why *are* you using `import sqlalchemy` AND `flask-sqlalchemy`? Wouldnt they both create the SQLAlchemy object and interfere with each other?

Answer (score 2):

Try to install it with these commands , (it worked for me):

```
pip install flask-sqlalchemy 


pip3 install flask-sqlalchemy
```

Refer this site for [**Example**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/flask_sqlalchemy.htm)

**or**

Refer the official guide site for [**installation**](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/intro.html#installation)

if it doesnt worked then try above `commands` with `--user` at the end of both commands

another solution maybe to install an IDE (if you are not using one) like PyCharm ; rather than a some simple text editors

First command installs package to python v2.x
Second one installs package to python 3.x

If you want to use 3.x to run your app ;then go to configuration and change it to python 3.x

Refer [**this**](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/support.html) for **Getting Help / Development / Bug reporting**

Answer (score 1):

Try using this command:

```
pip install flask-sqlalchemy --user
```

If you are using PyCharm go to file and select **Invalidate caches and restart**.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the name of your .py file. It may be causing a conflict with the `flask-sqlalchemy` package.

> "D:\PYTHON\GIT_EXC\FLASK_\flask_sqlalchemy.py"

Answer (score 1):

After adding :

```
app.app_context().push()
```

try this:

```
 db.session.commit()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue while instantiating airflow db by command

> ```
> $airflow db init 
> error: ImportError: cannot import name 'SQLAlchemyAutoSchema'
> ```

**Fixes:**

1. Uninstall:

   ```
   $pip uninstall marshmallow-sqlalchemy
   ```
2. Then upgrade it to version 0.24.0

   ```
   $pip3 install marshmallow-sqlalchemy==0.24.0
   ```

My problem resolved and able to initialize airflow db.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:

```
pip install flask-sqlalchemy --user
```

then install the missing dependencies if you see any errors as mentioned below:
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behavior is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
`spyder 5.4.3` requires `pyqt5<5.16`, which is not installed.
`spyder 5.4.3` requires `pyqtwebengine<5.16`, which is not installed.
`python-lsp-black 1.2.1` requires `black>=22.3.0`, but you have `black 0.0` which is incompatible.

Step 2:

```
pip install pyqt5
```

Step 3:

```
pip install pyqtwebengine
```

The above three steps solved my problem.